# PHP References removed by list()

Tags: php, variables, reference, php-7

I'm currently using PHP 7 in Debian (PHP Version 7.0.27-0+deb9u1) and got the following problem:

`list()` seems to strip off references. But I know some day in the past it didn't (maybe somewhere around PHP 5.3 or 5.4).

**Minimal (not) working example:**

```
$a=array('A');

$arr=array();
$arr[]=&$a;

var_dump($arr);

$arr[0]['X']='X';
list($entry)=$arr;
$entry['Z']='Z';

var_dump($arr);
```

**Expected output:**

```
/tmp/php_eval_ifEHDF:6:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)

/tmp/php_eval_ifEHDF:13:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      'X' => string 'X' (length=1)
      'Z' => string 'Z' (length=1)
```

**Real output:**

```
/tmp/php_eval_rdQjSm:6:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)

/tmp/php_eval_rdQjSm:12:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      'X' => string 'X' (length=1)
```

***Is this a bug or expected behaviour?***

Right now I'm using something like this to have the same result (I'd like to have a one-liner like with `list()`) but it looks ugly to me:

```
//minimal version (parenthesis unneeded here)
$entry=&($arr)[0];
//really used version
$entry=&(some_function_returning_arr())[0];
```

**But the following cannot be done with the above workaround:**

```
list($x, $y)=array(&a, &b);
//when changing $x, $a won't be changed as well :-(
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella strange...I know I wrote some code like this in 2012 that didn't kill the reference

Comment: @PaulCrovella Well, very strange. I guess I never had it working in 2012 and those people that actually should have checked it missed it, too. Thanks for your help anyway!